# Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have issue with some code and need some help please.

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number
> of elements in /content-woo-product.php on line 74 and line 86. +
> marked between +

Problem 1:

```
<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    
    $handle = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_ID());
    $variationData = $handle->get_children();
    
    $prices = array();
    foreach( $available_variations as $var ) {
      $prices[] = $var['display_price'];
      // print_r($var);
    }
    
    + $var_prices = array_combine($variations, $prices); +
    
    $var_prices_combine = array();
    
   
    $prod_id = get_the_ID();

    $merge_variation_id_price = array_combine($variationData, $prices);

    
    $variations = explode(',', $a['variations']);
    
    + $merge_varid_varattribute = array_combine($variationData, $variations); +



?>
```

Problem 2.

> Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number
> of elements in content-flower.php on line 382 and 386. *bolded*

```
   <?php while ($loop2->have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post();
          $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
          $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

          $handle = new WC_Product_Variable(get_the_ID());
          $variationData = $handle->get_children();
          
          $prices = array();
          foreach( $available_variations as $var ) {
            $prices[] = $var['display_price'];
          }

          // echo "<pre>";
          // print_r($variationData);
          // print_r($variations);
          // echo "</pre>";

          
          + $var_prices = array_combine($variations, $prices); +
          $var_prices_combine = array();
          $merge_variation_id_price = array_combine($variationData, $prices);
          $variations = explode(',', $a['variation1']);
           + $merge_varid_varattribute = array_combine($variationData, $variations); +
          $strains = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_strain' );
          $prod_id = get_the_ID();
        ?>
```

Comment: `$variations` seem to be set after the call to `array_combine()`? Did you check the contents of `$variations` and `$prices` when(right before) the warnings occur? What's `$a`?

Comment: I have file before the warnings occur and code is same , it worked then now I got this warnings.

Comment: Are they both run on the same server? It could be as simple as different error reporting level configurations.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same server. That's why am confused everything is the same as in previous version when it worked perfectly.

Comment: You didn't answer my other questions though..